# Alternative Tools to find memory leaks in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory-management

Can anybody tell if there are any tools other than CLANG static analyzer and the Memory Leak tools available in XCode.I am developing an application and it crashes after 10 mins of usage due to low memory.I have solved all the leaks pointed out by CLANG and the Tools of Xcode,but still not able to solve the low memory issue.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with Instruments? If memory growth is your problem, it will be able to show you what objects are still alive at a given point, hinting at the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application might not be leaking memory.  Low memory warnings can also be caused by an application retaining too much memory.  If you application is continually consuming memory, it could be that you are retaining references to objects when you shouldn't be.  Trying running inside of Instruments and monitor Memory Allocations.

Comment: But the problem is there are many objects that i cannot release during the life cycle of the whole application so memory keeps on accumulating

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that many objects are accumulating in memory, you need to modify your program so that this is not necessary. If they are downloaded, try saving to a file or files. Then you can re-load the objects into memory only when absolutely necessary. The iPhone has a fairly low memory threshold, so applications should be designed with this in mind. How much memory is being consumed? What objects are taking up all the space?